# Is it a good or bad practice to declare dtype when using pandas.read_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas

I remember that I was told in my master that if we know the dtype of the columns of our pandas data frame, it is always a good practice to declare dtype. This makes sense to arise bugs at a early stage or find error in our data. I believe that this make the code faster.

I did this in my job, and one of my supervisor told me that what is the point to do that if python does for us, this is a bad practice I was told.

I have been reading around and I can find an answer. I believe that this is a good practice but I am asking here, to confirm this and find reason that support this or on the contrary, learn something new.

Comment: Have you tried asking your supervisor why?

Comment: She says that, if python does for your, we don't have to and that way we make code simpler and more readable

Comment: This is question is off topic as it will elicit opinionated answers. See [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's typically just a matter of preference. For `read_csv()` I personally choose to let Pandas infer these details as there are so many parameters, and inferring the dtype is reliable (otherwise it wouldn't be optional); you're more likely to be wrong about these details than Pandas is.

However, being explicit with the dtype can be useful as the `low_memory` parameter is True by default, and as that processes the file in chunks, this has the risk of mixed types being inferred.

Inferring dtypes [is efficient](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.infer_dtype.html), so the performance improvement of passing it in is negligible.